# Averaging Grouped Data in Single SQL Statement Using Multiple Group Bys

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I want to see the average cost of an item. First I am using a SUM statement and GROUP BY the manufacturing order and Item to see how much each item costs per manufacturing order (using WHERE statements to take out specific steps in the process). Then I want to average those to see how much the item costs on average based on that set, can I do this easily in one statement instead on creating a temp table?

Comment: Where is the query you tried ? Also table structure, dummy data and expected result.

Comment: I figured it out right after I posted, thanks for the fast reply though!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take result in temp table if you first want to sum the cost of an item per manufacture order and perform average on total cost per item achieved from sum. I hope I understood your problem statement clearly.

SELECT item, AVG(cost) FROM
(SELECT item, manufacture_order, SUM(COST) cost 
FROM manufacture_order_tab 
GROUP BY item, manufacture_order) tab1
GROUP BY item;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT AVG(Cost), SUM(COST)
```

FROM your_table 
GROUP BY your_column